Fine tuning Gemma model that was downloaded from ollama
I am new to running models locally. I was very happy that I could run a gemma2b model locally which I pulled using ollama. I am using (or loading?) this local model in my python application by using chatOllama as below
llm = ChatOllama(model="gemma2")

But now I came to a stage where I want to fine tune this locally running model. I can see the model is saved in ~/.ollama/models/blobs as sha256.
But I understood from various reddit posts, chatgpt and general web browsing that I cannot fine-tune the model with ollama but I should somehow fine-tune this outside of ollama and then import it back to ollama to use the inference with fine-tuned model. is this understanding correct?
If yes, How do I actually take the model out of ollama to train and put it back? I understand GGUF is a model format that I can train. but how to get the GGUF for Gemma2 that is stored locally (in my case)
I am planning to use LoRA to train as I understood from some articles that it is efficient and uses fewer resources.
